# Is it possible to capture mouse events for a Silverlight control via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, dom-events, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

Since it appears Silverlight does not support the middle mouse button click event, is there a way to capture this event in JavaScript **when the user middle button clicks on the Silverlight control**? That way, I could pass the event on via a Javascript to Silverlight bridge.

Comment: Maybe - but it wouldn't be easy to translate that to a true mouse button (for Silverlight button clicks or other user-initiated actions)

Comment: Yeah, the more I dig into this, the more work it seems to require.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to have an HTML element overlay the silverlight <object> and have an onclick handler on that which then talks to the js to sl bridge? Main problem with that might be that it would also trap all the other events that you want to go to the Silverlight object as normal.

Comment: you don't need to have transparent overlay since I think the browser first grabs the events of plugins, then passes to the control (or the control internally grabs them, then passes to browser, then gets them back again via the DOM if browser let it do so). See how mousewheel functionality was added by users in first versions of Silverlight that didn't have such support

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it should work. Have you tried overlaying a transparent div ontop of the silverlight control to catch events and route them?